# Do “how to proceed” and “how to do” express the same meaning when giving instructions?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Since "proceed" generally means to continue a course of action, how do you understand the sentence "how to proceed" when used before instructions?

> How to Proceed
>
> 1. Step 01
> 2. Step 02
>
> How to Do
>
> 1. Step 01
> 2. Step 02

Here's a real example of "how to proceed" being used to introduce a series of steps http://www.ceracfp.ca/en/how-to-proceed, but I'm not sure it would be the case if I want to teach someone how to perform an exercise (e.g., meditation) or how to edit an image in Photoshop.

Comment: I have just looked at that French Canadian site. procéder in French is not necessarily proceed in English. For meditation: What do to OR How to meditate. Proceed would not be used here in English.

Answer (score 1):

[Proceed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proceed): meaning to continue as planned would be better than "How to do".  How to do what?

However, if writing instructions it is better to use a 'Task-oriented' Active voice, for example:

> To make a cup of coffee:
>
> 1. Fill kettle
> 2. Heat water to 87.6 C...
> 3. Select cup or mug
> 4. Select coffee of choice
> 5. etc....

"How to proceed" is a bit redundant as you 'proceed' to explain how to proceed...  So why not tell the user what they are about to do?